# What's the shutdown script mentioned in the IntelliJ stop button?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ documentation shows the following about the [Run Toolbar](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/run-tool-window.html) stop button:

> **Stop** (Ctrl+F2):   Click this button to terminate the current process externally by means of the standard `shutdown` script.

So what is that `shutdown` script? I'm wondering because the stop button does not seem to be doing anything in my application.

Comment: The script that's invoked to kill a process, such as building, compiling, running from terminal

Comment: Where is that script defined? Is it just `kill -INT` or something like that?

Comment: What kind of run configuration are you asking about?

Comment: Any run configuration. I can reproduce the issue with Kotlin, Java and Python.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the buttons in the Run tool window differ based on the run configuration. The page in the IntelliJ IDEA documentation you referenced says "The appearance of each tab depends on the type of the application being run and can include additional toolboxes and panes." and "The following table contains descriptions of the buttons that are common for most applications." It does appear to me that that documentation page could some improvement to describe more specifically what happens for different run configuration types.

For a straight Java application or running a JUnit test, in my experience it just kills the running process. When running Tomcat, the stop button runs the Tomcat `shutdown` script that's configured in its "Startup/Connection" tab (which I suspect is what the authors of that help page were thinking when they wrote that text).

If the stop button isn't doing what you're expecting for your application, I think you need to ask a separate question with more specific details about your specific circumstances. I think that the generic text in the documentation is probably sending you down the wrong track, as not all run configuration types have an equivalent "shutdown" script.